# Upgrading Mac OS 10.14.6 (Mojave) to Mac OS Ventura having the installer stored and running from a external drive

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, disk-space

I'm trying to upgrade Mac OS on my Powerbook. It is currently running Mojave. I've tried a regular (in-place) upgrade but it requires a ridiculous amount of free space on the MacBook Pro disc. The Ventura installer itself is worth 12 Gb so I was thinking in storing and running the installer from an external disk. It will allow me to gain 12 Gb of free space which may be enough for the installation. I'm not sure if I can boot normally from the Macbook Pro disk and run the installer from an external disk

Any help or other hints would be appreciated.

R

Comment: Why didn't you just try it & see?

Comment: Well, a system upgrade is not easily recoverable if it goes south. I was trying to save me some hassle in case it is something known to be wrong/not recommended

Comment: You need a Time Machine & also a complete clone anyway before trying a jump as far as this. Belt & braces. There's no cutting corners.